# Silverstripe - return form data after validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, silverstripe

I am trying to do server side validation with custom validation for the phone and email fields. I am doing the custom validation in the forms action.

Firstly is this the correct place to do it and secondly if so how can I get the data to return to the form if it doesn't meet validation?

Currently it will clear the entire form.

```
public function doSubmitForm($data, Form $form) {

        if (!preg_match("/^[\+_a-z0-9-'&=]+(\.[\+_a-z0-9-']+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$/i",$data['Email'])) {
            $form->addErrorMessage('Email', 'Invalid email', 'bad');
        return $this->redirectBack();
        }
        if (!preg_match("/^((?:\+)|0)(\d{9,14})$/i",$data['Phone'])) {
            $form->addErrorMessage('Phone', 'Please match the correct format eg: 0821234567', 'bad');
        return $this->redirectBack();
        }

        $form->sessionMessage('Thank you for your submission','alert alert-success');

    return $this->redirectBack();   
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you don't do server-side validation like that. 
The easiest way is just to use the proper form-fields. Eg. `EmailField` and `PhoneNumberField`.

If these don't validate the way you want, just extend them or create your own `FormField` subclasses.

Here's how `EmailField` does it's validation: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.5/forms/EmailField.php#L39

Alternatively you could also implement a custom validator by extending `Validator` or `RequiredFields`. The validator will be applied to the whole form though and if you start validating individual field types there, you'd be better off just implementing the field as custom class (that way you have a re-usable component).

Comment: Thank you. I see email validation is okay. It would just be phone number that I need to make sure is at least 10 characters. I read up about extending `Validator`but not following it exactly. 
`$required = new RequiredFields(array('Name', 'Email', 'Phone'));
        $form = new Form($this, 'MyForm', $fields, $actions);  
        $form->setValidator($required);`
So I need to make a custom phone class and do the validation there?

Comment: I suggest you just create a custom subclass of `TextField`, maybe `PhoneField` and implement the `validate` method there (with your phone-number validation). You can take the code of `EmailField` as a starting-point…

Comment: for validating phone numbers https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php might be a good tool.

Answer (score 1):

I had to implement a 10 characters length for phone numbers the other day.

https://github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-zenvalidator

I included the module above via composer and followed the set up in the README.

For the admin interface I created a getCMSValidator() method

```
public function getCMSValidator() {
    $validator = ZenValidator::create();
    $validator->setConstraint('Phone', Constraint_length::create('range', 10, 10)->setMessage('Phone numbers must be 10 digits in length'));
    $validator->setConstraint('PhoneAH', Constraint_length::create('range', 10, 10)->setMessage('Phone numbers must be 10 digits in length'));
    $validator->setConstraint('PhoneMobile', Constraint_length::create('range', 10, 10)->setMessage('Mobile numbers must be 10 digits in length'));
    $validator->disableParsley();
    return $validator;
}
```

For the front end just create a $validator and then add it to the form

```
$validator = ZenValidator::create();
$validator->setConstraint('Phone', Constraint_length::create('range', 10, 10)->setMessage('Phone numbers must be 10 digits in length'));
$validator->disableParsley();

$Form = new Form($this, 'FormName', $fields, $actions, $validator);
```

Took me about 20 minutes to implement that minimum 10 & maximum 10 characters on about 5 or 6 different forms.

I hope this helps.

Cheers,
Colin